# Do we need a separate Metadata server to use pNFS?

Tags: rhel, nfs

So we upgraded some of our servers to RHEL 6.5 and I came across pNFS while reading through the release docs. According to various docs available online, the performance improvement is huge over traditional NFS. Sadly, the docs available online about configuring pNFS are not very helpful. I have just this one question:

Do we need a separate Metadata server to use pNFS? Example: If I have one NFS server and 10 clients in traditional NFS setup, do I need to have one NFS server, one Metadata server and those 10 clients if I am to implement pNFS there?

Comment: Just checked with the guys at Redhat. They say that we do need a separate Metadata server, but what is weird is that they don't support pNFS Server yet. They support only pNFS clients. Meaning, we can have pNFS clients, but for pNFS server, we have use a 3rd party solution.